# cannot choose a unique locator to click an element - selenium java krypton

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, krypton

I need to have a unique locator since i cannot use text because it both have facility, I need to click this

[image]

here is my sample code right now but it does not click

```
findLink(By.xpath("//*[ng-click()='promptGroupDrawerCtrl.closeDrawer()']")).click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Facility** you can use the following solution:

```
findLink(By.xpath("//a[@class='h4 panel-heading panel-back panel-title btn ng-binding' and contains(@ng-click,'closeDrawer')]")).click
```

**Note**: As the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*

Comment: That locator is horrible. You have a massive string match... if any one of those classes changes or one is added or one is removed, the whole thing is broken. There's no need to use XPath here. It would be much better to use a CSS selector and avoid all this.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with the `xpath`:

`ng-click` is an attribute, not a method. Remove the round brackets.

Attribute name should start with `@`

```
findLink(By.xpath("//*[@ng-click='promptGroupDrawerCtrl.closeDrawer()']")).click();
```